# sed + add comment to IP - only if IP is matched exactly

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

my target is to add "#" to the IP's with sed,

But Only if IP is matched exactly!!!

for example:

```
 sed 's/72.16.90.12/#72.16.90.12/g' /etc/hosts



 more /etc/hosts

 72.16.90.121   host1
 172.16.90.12   host2
```

the below sed command will add "#" to the IP's in the hosts file in spite they not match

what I need to add to my sed syntax in order to add the "#" only in case IP's are full identical??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add *word boundaries*, and change `.` to `\.` (so as to match literal periods, instead of any characters)

```
sed 's/\b72\.16\.90\.12\b/#&/g'
```

Also note the use of `&` to save having to duplicate the replacement. You probably don't need the `g` modifier either in this context, since your host addresses are one per line.

Answer (score 0):

```
IP=10.10.10.10   # change to yours
sed -i -e "/${IP}/s/${IP}/#${IP}/" /etc/hosts
```